# Matlab can't find publish file. Where is it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have found the publish menu in Matlab. I would like to reference it in my code so as to save output ( without the commands) and all figures. I am using only figure1 throughout. I want to save in two formats pdf and doc.

Where do I put the publish command at the beginning or at the end of my code or putting it another way should I execute the publish commands at beginning? Matlab software keeps telling me it cannot find the file? Further I want to include all graphs. I have added snapnow after each plot.

I have used the following code both at beginning and end of my program. I want to include all graphs but no input commands only output. Options can be seen on edit publishing options window. I tried to start simple.

Code:

```
publish('c:\data\output.doc')
publish('c:\data\output.doc','doc')
```

Error message

```
Cannot find "c:\data\output.doc".
```

Thank you.
MM

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you tried?

Comment: The first argument to publish command is the MATLAB file name. Not the output file name.